# What is an best way of manipulating millions of records and saving back to database with option to cancel and pause?

Tags: django, multithreading, postgresql, python-2.7

Am using Django with python 2.7. am having an excel sheet with millions of rows. I have to manipulate rows data and save back to database (postgresql). I want to do it efficiently. Following are the approaches am thinking of :

> 1.) enqueue all the rows (data) in a queue (preferably RabbitMQ) and will fetch with a bunch of 100 entries at once. and will execute and
>   will save it in database.
>
> 2.) thinking of using thread in background which will be managing 100 rows by each thread and will save back the result to database. I'm not
>   sure how many database connections will be opened in this scenario.

Can you please suggest me an efficient way to achieve this. it will be really very helpful.

How to implement cancel and pause logic in this scenario? should i be using a database ?

Comment: why not copy csv to postgres directly? would be the fastest I assume

Comment: i have to manipulate on each row

Comment: often popular ETL approach is copy csv to table and insert select form that table adding logic to select